# Android shared preference not working

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am developing an Android app where I am trying to save some values using the sharedPreference concept. I am just trying the basic things for saving something into the SharedPreference. But its not working. Here is what am trying to do:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString(SHARED_PREF_USER_NAME, "username");
editor.putString(SHARED_PREF_PASSWORD, "password");
editor.commit();
System.out.println("SHARED_PREF_USER_NAME ::" + 
                     preferences.getString(SHARED_PREF_USER_NAME, ""));
System.out.println("SHARED_PREF_PASSWORD ::" + 
                     preferences.getString(SHARED_PREF_PASSWORD, ""));
```

Just below the code, I am trying to print the values that were saved into the SharedPreference. But am getting the empty string.

Comment: `commit()` returns a boolean which tells you whether the preference was written to persistent memory. Perhaps print that result?

Comment: It is possible thats you are confused with the values? `editor.putString(key, value)` is correct. Seems thats you swapped the two strings. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seams to be ok, I ran it on a test project and got the correct output. Maybe it's about your preference strings? Do they contain spaces?

Means if `String SHARED_PREF_USER_NAME = "user name"` then Change it to `"username"` and Try.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("username",SHARED_PREF_USER_NAME);
editor.putString("password",SHARED_PREF_PASSWORD);
editor.commit();
System.out.println("SHARED_PREF_USER_NAME ::" + 
                     preferences.getString(SHARED_PREF_USER_NAME, ""));
System.out.println("SHARED_PREF_PASSWORD ::" + 
                     preferences.getString(SHARED_PREF_PASSWORD, ""));
```

Comment: Thats whats probably is the problem?!